# Class 'Craft\DbCommand' not found

Tags: database, error-message, installation

Getting this error in the PHP error log file while trying to install craft.

**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Craft\DbCommand' not found**

The file is there, permissions are granted and I've tried reinstalling twice. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a file is missing/corrupt.  Can you try again with a fresh copy of Craft from http://buildwithcraft.com?

Comment: Now I'm just getting a flash of a 500 error in the console on refresh, and then nothing. There's no log anymore either, since I completely reinstalled it.

Comment: You're following the installation instructions here? http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing

Comment: I am, although I'm putting it in a subfolder since I don't want it to be the main site yet. I've done that before and haven't had any issues...

Comment: Now I got "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Craft\InfoModel' not found" in the php log a twice (but not every time I refresh so I don't think that's the issue anymore. I'm getting "Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in .../public/index.php" on the page now. I know the path is correct and the permissions are set to 774.

Comment: Maybe you've got PHP `openbase_dir` restrictions in place?

Comment: it's set to {WEBSPACEROOT}/:{TMP}/

Comment: Looks like your host is doing some fancy stuff with dynamic paths in `openbase_dir`. I'd contact them and let them know what you're seeing. 95% chance that's the cause of it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue, @strohrdanz?

Comment: @MattStein nope... think i switched hosting. it was awhile ago this happened

Comment: Bummer. I guess there's no perfect ending to this post, then. Thanks for responding @strohrdanz, and sorry you had to switch hosts to avoid the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Even thought this is an old thread, I recently ran in to the same problem. It turned out to be a PHP version issue. I was running MAMP with PHP 7.0.0, once I switched that host to 5.6.10 it worked perfectly.

Comment: Craft is compatible with PHP 7 since 2.5 — are you running an older version?

Comment: We have a site running Craft v2.3.2620 where I ran into this issue and  where this solution worked in resolving it too.